# How to use hex number in bash command

Tags: bash, hex

I can see many places where it is explained how to convert between hex numbers and decimal numbers when you want to print it out.
I don't want to print it, I want to use the hex value in a command.

```
currentAdress=$((0x$currentAdress + 8))
# read the max_payload
maxPayloadCmd="sudo /sbin/setpci -d $vendorId:$deviceId $currentAdress.B"
maxPayload=`eval $maxPayloadCmd`
```

The value `currentAdress` is a string on the range of `00` to `FF`

When I Print `maxPayloadCmd`, I can see that I have the decimal value there, not the `hexvalue`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `maxPayloadCmd` like this. Define a function instead, for example: `max_payload () { sudo /sbin/setpci -d "$1:$2" "$3.B"; }`, then call it as `max_payload "$vendorID" "$deviceID" "$currentAddress"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` with `%x` to print a value in hex.

```
maxPayloadCmd="sudo /sbin/setpci -d $vendorId:$deviceId $(printf '%02x.B' $currentAdress)"
```

By the way, it'd be more natural to store the command in a function rather than a variable. You should [avoid eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in general.

```
maxPayload() {
    sudo /sbin/setpci -d "$vendorId:$deviceId" "$(printf '%02x.B' "$currentAdress")"
}
```

```
# Call the function the same as any other command.
maxPayload
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on how you print your variable:

```
$ currentAdress=2
$ currentAdress=$((0x$currentAdress + 8))
$ printf "%d\n" $currentAdress
10
$ printf "%x\n" $currentAdress
a
```

Comment: I dont want to print it, as I said. I want to execute it.
It should be like this:
sudo /sbin/setpci -d 8086:2f08 88.B

But it is:
sudo /sbin/setpci -d 8086:2f08 136.B

Comment: @Megadavve You literally want a string representation of a particular value, so `printf` is the right way to go. You can capture the output with `x=$(printf '%x' "$currentAdress")`, or use the `bash` extension `printf -v x '%x' "$currentAdress"`.